# Table grid glitches on certain zoom level

Tags: tables

When writing tables in LaTeX I sometime notice with various PDF viewer the same glitches that only seem to appear on certain zoom level.

Any explanation?

[image]

Another example of these glitches, but this time in the opposite direction:

[image]

Here a minimal example (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53253/85416)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \caption{Table showing Feature 5's Functional Tests}
    \hspace*{-0.5in}
    \begin{tabular}[h!]{|p{0.6cm}|p{4cm}|p{5cm}|p{4cm}|p{1.5cm}|}
    \hline
    {\bf Test ID } & {\bf Task } & {\bf Expected} & {\bf Actual} & {\bf Outcome} \\
    \hline
       5.1 & Something &  Something & Something &  Success \\
    \hline
       5.2 & Something &  Something & Something &  Success \\
    \hline
       5.3 & Something &  Something & Something &  Success \\
    \hline
       5.4 & Something &  Something & Something &  Success \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without knowing the code that gives this result, no one can answer you. Write an MWE: [How to make a “minimum example”](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl)

Comment: As I understand it PDF viewers will snap lines to pixel boundaries (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53935), so if you only see this at some zoom levels in some viewers, it's probably just something like that. (I'm no expert though.)

Comment: I don't know why but a solution is to use `\usepackage{array}` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63153/85416)

Answer (score 1):

From the [array](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf) package one can read:

> With standard LATEX boxed tabulars actually have strange corners because
> the horizontal rules end in the middle of the vertical ones. This looks very
> unpleasant when a large \arrayrulewidth is chosen. In that case a simple
> table like

```
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline A \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

So using `\usepackage{array}` may solve your issue.